# How to access shared folders set up on Windows 7 using a Windows 8 machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, network-shares, file-sharing, shared-folders

I set up several shared drives and folders on my Win 7 machines, so that any new machine running Win 7 with the same user name and password log in can use those drives and folders.

But on Win 8, I need to log in using my MSN (or Windows Live or soon to be Skype account)... so the user name and password are different from my Win 7 machines... so whenever I access those shared drives and folders (or just the machine), it will say access denied, without asking me to enter user name or password.

In this case, is there an easy way to read / write files to those shared drives and folders?

P.S. it is very strange... I can access one of my Win 7 machines but not the other one... while all other Win 7 machines can access any other Win 7 machines...

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Credential Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon) to add the [Win7 username/password](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/systems-administrator/migrating-saved-website-and-terminal-services-passwords-with-windows-7-credential-manager-102201).

[image]

Comment: by the way I found that the user name `mike` will not work.  It has to be `LENOVO\mike` and `LENOVO` is the name of my Win 8 machine

Comment: this is correct. if you use it without the server name Windows would use your local PC and look there for this account.